# Proving unit with a condition

Tags: ring-theory

In a ring $R$ with identity, if $a^{2}=a$, where $a\in R$, then show that $1-2a$ is a unit. Please give me the proper explanation.

Answer (score 2):

$(1-2a)(1-2a) = (1-2a)^2 = 1 -4a + 4a^2 = 1$

By definition $x$ is a unit iff it has an inverse element $y$, i.e. $xy=1$. In this case $x=y=(1-2a)$.